# Convert JSON to DF in R

Tags: json, r, parsing

I have a large data file filled up of key value pairs. The key is an ID and the value is a huge json object. I have been trying to convert this data file to a df in R, by importing the data as a 2 column table and then converting the value to a data frame.

I keep getting this error, even after I validated my json.

> Error: lexical error: invalid string in json text.
>
> ```
>                                 [{ f: { SEQNUM: [ 455043, 455044, 
>                  (right here) ------^
> ```

below is my code

```
part00013 <- read.table(PatientData, sep = '\t', header = F, as.is = T)
colnames(part00013) <- c('k','v')
make_indexDateLists <- function(x) {
#  x['v'] <- lapply(x['v'], function(y) as.character(y))
#  x['v'] <- lapply(x['v'], function(y) substr(y,1, nchar(y)-1 ))
#  x['v'] <- lapply(x['v'], function(y) substr(y,2,nchar(y)))              
  x["v"] <- lapply(as.character(x["v"]), function(y) jsonlite::fromJSON(y,simplifyVector = T))
  
  #do assignpatienttocohorts
  
  x["v"] <- lapply(x["v"], function(y) RJSONIO::toJSON(y))
  
  cbind(x$k, x$v)
}

make_indexDateLists(part00013)
```

and here is a sample file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6hKduYaYwdJQ3BwbUpNSW9EZk0

Comment: ignore the various packages for JSON, I tried all of them

Comment: you are really quick to judge the packages vs your own abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's invalid JSON, but you can turn it into valid JSON:

```
library(stringi)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

tmp <- readLines("oneline_part00013")

parts <- stri_split_fixed(tmp, "\t", 2)[[1]]

fromJSON(parts[2], flatten = FALSE) %>%
  glimpse()
## Observations: 1
## Variables: 7
## $ f <data.frame> 455043, 455044, 455045, 455046, 455047, 455048, 45504...
## $ s <data.frame> 246549, 246550, 246551, 246552, 246553, 246554, 24655...
## $ i <data.frame> 8224, 8788, 770102, 30, 10, 30, 3301, 3301, 3301, 192...
## $ d <data.frame> 1114386, 1114387, 1114388, 1114389, 1114390, 1114391,...
## $ o <data.frame> 162072527, 162072528, 162072529, 162072530, 162072531...
## $ t <data.frame> 408352, 408353, 408354, 408355, 408356, 408357, 40835...
## $ a <data.frame> 36527, 42259, 35562, 42458, 39119, 30, 10, 30, 20, 30...
```

`flatten = TRUE` will un-nest all the `data.frame` columns (you'll end up with over 450 columns that way)